# Cannot import modules using Virtualenv in Vagrant

Tags: python, linux, vagrant, virtualenv

This is my first time trying to set up a vagrant environment or a python virtuelenv, so forgive me if I am missing something basic.

Right now, I ssh into my vagrant box and in the home directory I have placed my venv folder. I have run

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

From my home directory I move to /vagrant, and within here I have my project files laid out something like this:

```
├──project
├── LICENSE
│
├── project
│   │   ├── exceptions.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── target
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   │       └── test.py
│   ├── README.md
```

My problem is I am unable to import my modules in different directories. For example, if I am in /vagrant/project/project/target/test.py and I attempt:

```
import project.exceptions
```

I will get the error

```
ImportError: No module named project.exceptions
```

If I am in the /vagrant/project/project directory and I run

```
import exceptions
```

that works fine.

I have read up on similar problems people have experienced on StackOverflow.

Based on this question: [Can't import package from virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308862/cant-import-package-from-virtualenv) I have checked that my sys.executable path is the same in both my python interpreter as well as when I run a script (home/vagrant/venv/bin/python)

Based on this question: [Import error with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909025/import-error-with-virtualenv). I have run ~/venv/bin/python directly and attempted to import, but the import still fails.

Let me know if there is more information I can provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can install your project into the virtual environment, by writing a setup.py file and by calling `python setup.py install`. See the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).
2. You can set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to point to your project, like this:

   ```
   $ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/vagrant/project
   ```

Comment: This worked! I tried option 2 and it all works now. Thank you so much for your help!