# Python 3 VirtualEnv ImportError: No module named djangocms_admin_style

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, module

I am migrating a Django project to production and was going through `python manage.py collectstatic` phase.

After running this command, I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named djangocms_admin_style

However, I clearly have this module installed as both `pip list` and a manual inspection of the directories shows.

What's more, preceeding this error, there is the following traceback:

> File "manage.py", line 10, in
>
> ```
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> ```
>
> line 354, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>
> line 328, in execute
>       django.setup()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 18,
>
> in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
>   85, in populate
>
> ```
> app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line
> ```
>
> 86, in create
>
> ```
> module = import_module(entry)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in
> ```
>
> import_module
>       **import**(name)

What confuses me about the traceback is that there are multiple references to the system-wide Python instead of the one I created within the virtualenv. Why is that? I suspect that this has something to do with the error above.

If it helps, I do not have anything custom (including `django_admin_styles`) installed in the system Python environment, only within my virtualenv, which is also activated when the commands are run.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VSCode by any chance? Along with setting up the environment, you need to reference the correct python executable by setting the "python.pythonPath" setting to the path of the python executable inside your virtual environment.

Comment: No. I had to add an extra app to Installed Apps of Django.